# Select a record based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has a column row filled with a Javascript's, `Date.now()` function.
The column name is **update_time**, and its sample value is `1571152209099`.

How can I make a Select for all rows that have todays date (taking into account only year, month and a day)?

I have tried something like this, but it get's me nowhere.

```
Select *
from program_end
where workout_rate between 0 and 1
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(update_time, '%YYYY-%MM-%DD') = CURDATE()
```

I also tried changing the time format:

```
Select *
from program_end
where FROM_UNIXTIME(update_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

But no result whatsoever.
Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For insight, consider:

```
 SELECT '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL ( 1571152209099 /1000) SECOND
```

returns:

```
_dt                         
--------------------------
2019-10-15 15:10:09.099000
```

We recognize that the `1571152209099` value from JavaScipt `Date.now()` is integer milliseconds from the beginning of the era (Jan 1, 1970 midnight UTC).

Also consider:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01 00:00','2019-10-15 00:00')*1000 AS _dt_1
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01 00:00','2019-10-16 00:00')*1000 AS _dt_2
```

returns:

```
        _dt_1           _dt_2
-------------  --------------
1571097600000   1571184000000
```

The TIMESTAMPDIFF function is returning a difference in seconds; we multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.

We recognize that any JavaScript `Date.now()` milliseconds value that is greater than or equal to `_dt_1` and is less than `_dt_2` occurs sometime "on" the date `'2109-10-15'`

---

So, given `update_time` is milliseconds since the beginning of the era...

In a query, I would compare the bare `update_time` column to two literal values:

```
WHERE update_time >= 1571097600000 
  AND update_time <  1571184000000
```

Referencing the bare column has the advantage that MySQL can make use of an efficient range scan operation, with a suitable index available.

To derive those millisecond values from a given date value, we can do a calculation in an expression, like this:

```
WHERE update_time >= TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', '2019-10-15' )*1000 
  AND update_time <  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01', '2019-10-15' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)*1000
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Those expressions on the right side get evaluated just one time at the start of the statement execution.

Note that if we wrap `update_time` in a function, then that function has to be evaluated for every value of `update_time`, for every row in the table (that isn't filtered out by some other predicate.)

Comment: It took me sometime to get this in my head. Here is the query I come up following your suggestions. It returns all entries for todays date: SELECT *
from program_end
where workout_rate BETWEEN 0 AND 1 AND
update_time > TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01 00:00',CURDATE()) * 1000
  AND update_time < TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01 00:00',CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000

Comment: @VedranMaricevic.:  I think we would not to consider the first millisecond of the day to be included... so I would use a `>=` comparison on the low side, and the `<` on the high side.  If we do that, then for the next day, there is no "gap" and no "overlap" on the boundary. Those expressions on the right side do start to look complicated, but its possible to unwind them. We can also test those expressions in the SELECT list of a separate statement, before we incorporate them into a WHERE clause. We prefer predicates on bare columns (to allow effective use of indexes for performance)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's `Date.now` is giving you *milliseconds*, whereas MySQL's `FROM_UNIXTIME` expects *seconds*.

Unable to understand the epoch timestamp in milliseconds, `FROM_UNIXTIME` is returning NULL, which is of course failing to match the current date.

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1571152209099);
+------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1571152209099) |
+------------------------------+
| NULL                         |  -- THIS IS YOUR PROBLEM
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1571152209099/1000);
+-----------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1571152209099/1000) |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2019-10-15 10:10:09.0990          |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Try this:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(update_time/1000), format...)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have dates in the future, you can simply do:

```
WHERE update_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
```

This will happily use an existing index on `update_time`.

If you have dates in the future that you need to exclude from the resultset, then:

```
WHERE 
    update_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) 
    AND update_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```